# issue with html form input pattern option

Tags: html, css

Hello I have this issues with html input form pattern that allow only alphabet.
Here is the code:

```html
<form name="lineform" id="line-form" action="main.html" method="POST" onsubmit="insertDB(event,'line')">
  <div>
    <p class="labels required">Channel Name:</p>
    <p class="labels"><input pattern="[A-Za-z]+" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Please enter on alphabets only. ')" type="text" id="chname" name="chname" value="" placeholder="Enter your Channel Name" style="width: 700px;" required></p>
  </div><br>
  <div>
    <p class="labels required">Channel Id:</p>
    <p class="labels "><input type="text" id="chid" name="chid" value="" placeholder="Enter your Channel ID" style="width: 700px;" required></p>
  </div><br>
  <div>
    <p class="labels required">Channel Access Tokenn:</p>
    <p class="labels "><input type="text" id="chtoken" name="chtoken" value="" placeholder="Enter your Channel Access Token" style="width: 700px;" required></p>
  </div><br>



  <div>
    <button style="background-color:#1f73b7; color:white; width:8%; height: 35px; border: none; border-radius: 3px;" type="submit">Submit</button>
  </div><br>

</form>
```

The code work fine if I enter the number and submit it, it won't work and show warning but I tried to remove the number and input letter it still showing the same errors message that I need to provide only alphabets. Any ideas how can I fix this?

Comment: try setting onInvalid attribute to a javascript function that takes the event as parameter. check the pattern inside that function and return true or false based on the event.target.value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you are not clearing the `setCustomValidity` message and reporting validity when the input becomes valid.

See the example here:[`setCustomValidity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLObjectElement/setCustomValidity#examples)

```
 else
   {
     input.setCustomValidity('');
     input.reportValidity();
   }
```

> It's vital to set the message to an empty string if there are no errors. As long as the error message is not null, the form will not pass validation and will not be submitted.

---

Updated example:

```js
document.getElementById("chname").addEventListener('invalid', function() {
  const validityState_object = this.validity;

  if (validityState_object.patternMismatch) {
    this.setCustomValidity('Please enter on alphabets only. ');
    this.reportValidity();
  } else {
    this.setCustomValidity('');
    this.reportValidity();
  }
});
```

```css
button {
  background-color: #1f73b7;
  color: white;
  width: 8%;
  height: 35px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

input {
  width: 700px;
}
```

```html
<form name="lineform" id="line-form" action="main.html" method="POST">
  <div>
    <p class="labels required">Channel Name:</p>
    <p class="labels"><input pattern="[A-Za-z]+" type="text" id="chname" name="chname" value="" placeholder="Enter your Channel Name" required></p>
  </div><br>
  <div>
    <p class="labels required">Channel Id:</p>
    <p class="labels "><input type="text" id="chid" name="chid" value="" placeholder="Enter your Channel ID" required></p>
  </div><br>
  <div>
    <p class="labels required">Channel Access Tokenn:</p>
    <p class="labels "><input type="text" id="chtoken" name="chtoken" value="" placeholder="Enter your Channel Access Token" required></p>
  </div><br>

  <div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </div><br>
</form>
```

Comment: @PanhaSeav This was interesting... please check updated answer.